# Is there a difference between the paths . and .\ for gcc in windows?

Tags: c, windows, gcc

I want to compile a c-file with the path `.\test\test.c`. The file includes a .h-file in the current working directory.

gcc compiles the file when I run:
`gcc -c .\test\test.c -o .\test.o  -I .`

However, it fails when I run:
`gcc -c .\test\test.c -o .\test.o  -I .\`

Giving me the following error message:

```
.\test\test.c:13:10: fatal error: clib_string.h: No such file or directory
 #include "clib_string.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

This makes me wonder if there is a difference between the paths `.` and `.\` in windows or if this is just a quirk of gcc?

Comment: Which shell are you using? Plain CMD?

Comment: I see this in both plain CMD and in PowerShell.

Comment: Did you reproduce that in isolation (i.e. create a [mcve])? If so, the answer is "yes.", as you have proven yourself then.

Comment: Yes, test.c is only main function and clib_string.h is completely empty. 
`
#include "clib_string.h"

int main()
{
  return 0;
}`

Comment: What happens if you use `./` (forward slash, yes, Windows knows how to interpret this at many places) instead of backslash?

Comment: When using `./` gcc does not find the header file as when using `.\ ` .

Comment: What happens if you use a full path, is there a difference if it ends with \ or not?

Comment: GCC compiles when using full path, both when it ends with \ and when not. Relative paths also work including weird ones like `.\test\..\.\ ` . Update: I found it works when using the path `.\.\ `.